# SMS encryption/decryption in J2ME

Tags: java-me, sms, encryption

I want to encrypt and decrypt SMS with J2ME, i tried `TEA` algorithm, but it generates a long encrypted text.
Is there any other lightweight algorithm that generates an encrypted text with the same length as original text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check stream [chiphers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher) (like RC4). Those won't increase space need. Encrypted data has same length than plain data.

If you want to encrypt 7-bit text message witch can be 160 chars. Then those does not help. 
But if maximum length of plain text is 140 bytes, then those can be used.

Comment: i use RC4 with Cipher.getInstance("RC4"), but it increase the data length to the duplicate, 160 chars becomes 320 char.

Comment: RC4 is not supported in J2ME :(

Comment: @Dahmad Boutfounast : You can always write it for J2ME, it is simple. But RC4 have some weakness. Consider some other stream chiper if security level must be high.

Comment: @Dahmad Boutfounast : Nope, RC4 does not duplicate the length. You probably convert chiper text to hex dump. That duplicates it. If you want to use hexdump, then you can use 7-bit encoding in SMS. But it limits maximum message size to 80 bytes (160/2). If you can use 8-bit encoding in SMS messages and not hexdump, then 140 bytes messages can be used. Of cource you can try to encrypt payload of 7-bit coded SMS PDU, but it will be bore tricky.

Comment: for the length, yes i was using a hex function, now i am using encoding with Base64, it only increase the length with some bytes (120 chars gives 160 chars encrypted and coded).

Comment: as final solution, i am using AES in CTR mode, it acts like CR4 but it's more secure.

Answer (score 1):

Stream encryption does work for this, but even stream encryption is only working on bits. So you need to compress the text to fit in as few bits as possible. Using deflation would work in most cases, but may fail on shorter messages or messages that contain uncompressable data.

Another way is to compress your message into as few bits as possible yourself. E.g. the numbers 0..9 are ASCII `30h` to `39h`. But they may also be stored in binary form `0000` to `1001` binary. Packed BCD would be a good option for encoding numbers. Mathematic majors would immediately see you can use groups and division for minimum storage requirements, but that may add quite a lot of CPU resources (never mind the fun developing that solution). Once you have the shortest binary representation you encrypt with the stream cipher.

So now you have this nice short binary representation. Hopefully it will fit into the SMS message. If not, you need to encode the resulting binary representation.

Basically, what you need to do is:

```
send = Send(EncodeBin(Encrypt(EncodeTxt(plain))))
```

then

```
plain = DecodeTxt(Decrypt(DecodeBin(Receive(send))))
```

But don't let that stop you :)